# convert dataframe to the heatmap matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation, data-science

I have a pandas data frame with the structure like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entry': [['A','B','C'],['A','B','E','D'],['C'],['D','A', 'B'],['D','C','E'],['E','A']]})
```

which gives:

```
    entry
0   [A, B, C]
1   [A, B, E, D]
2   [C]
3   [D, A, B]
4   [D, C, E]
5   [E, A]
```

I want to convert it to the **square matrix**,  size of unique symbols seen in the data frame (in this case it is 5: 'A','B','C','D','E')  where every intersection is the frequency of this pair been seen together (like here the pair [A,B] is seen together 3 times, pair [D,A] - only once. If there are 3 or more symbols together, I want all the combinations to be considered.) So the output is something like this:

```
   A B C D E
A    3 1 1 1
B        1 1
C        1 1
D          2
E
```

I am quite a beginner in the field, tried to write a loop that goes through all the combinations. Have a problem with the fact that there may be any amount of items inside the entry.

Comment: Do you want order to matter in your result? If so you would need a full result matrix, which is not shown. If not, there should (for one example) be a 2 in the (A,D) entry because (A,D) appears in row 1 and (D,A) appears in row 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work if you want unordered pairs.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# First get a DataFrame (or could be a Series) of the pairwise combinations in each row
combinations = df['entry'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(sorted(x), 2)))

# Then get a list of unique values - A,B,C,D,E
unique_values = sorted(list(set(
    symbol for symbol_list in df.values.flatten() for symbol in symbol_list)))

# Create empty dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=unique_values, index=unique_values)

# Iterate through symbols and fill dataframe
for symbol_pair in list(itertools.combinations(unique_values, 2)):
    result.loc[symbol_pair[0], symbol_pair[1]] = combinations.apply(lambda x: symbol_pair in x).sum()
```